# Modelling of probabilistic vs deterministic systems

Tags: modeling, expected-value, statistical-learning

The learning problem in Statistical Learning Theory is defined as:

$$
R(f) = \int_{X,Y} L(y, f(x))P(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
$$

where

- $R(f)$ is the expected risk
- $L$ is the loss function
- $P(x, y)$ is the probability distribution defined over the set $X \times Y$
- $f(x)$ is the predicted output

Now, $P(x, y)$ is **unknown** to us.

I have a few questions about the formulation of the learning problem defined above.

1. When we assume that the data $(x, y)$ is generated using the probability distribution $P(x, y)$, we also implicitly assume one of the *inference models* given below:

   - **Model based inference**: The system we're trying to model is *probabilistic* and not *deterministic*
   - **Design based inference**: The way we *interact* with the system (our experimental setup) is *probabilistic* while the system we model is *deterministic*

   Which of the above inference models is assumed by Statistical Learning Theory?
2. If Statistical Learning Theory does assume one of the inference models given above, is there any parallel theory in Statistics that's based on the other inference model?

Comment: The distinction you draw between modeling approaches is similar to how I distinguish Bayesian and frequentist modeling in my own mind. I'm not sure if my distinction is correct but I suspect there's a connection

Comment: As a matter of terminology, the first bullet is called a "model-based approach" while the second is a "design-based approach." [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=model-based+randomness&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) will provide literature examples.  As far as (2) goes, I'm not sure what you are asking, because it is unclear to which "techniques" you refer and even the sense of "fundamentally different" seems a little vague.  Perhaps you could elaborate on these points?

Comment: @whuber Updated the question

Comment: Your $R(f)$ is defined exactly in the way the optimal forecasting problem is.